# Cell color change on multiple values copy paste

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone please help on Excel VBA coding, I want to change the colors of cells when the values are changed on single go with copy paste on certain range, say `"A1:B10"`

I am able to perform for a single cell copy paste as below , but not sure how to perform the same for multiple cells,

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:K20")) Is Nothing Then
    If oldValue <> Target.Value Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(184, 245, 198)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: your code does do multiple cells. You can add another If Not Intersect for an additional range.... and along the lines of the current answer below you can have Range("B2:K20").Interior.Color =  if you want all the cells in the intersect coloured.

Comment: what is `oldValue`? is this inside some `Worksheet_Change()` event handler and you want to monitor any actual change? you may want to add some more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through your `Target`, like in the code below:

```
Dim C As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:K20")) Is Nothing Then
    ' loop through cells in range
    For Each C In Target
        If oldValue <> C.Value Then
            C.Interior.Color = RGB(184, 245, 198)
        End If
    Next C
End If
```